# How to determine if a Javascript self-referencing loop completes

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop

I have a situation where I need to read all the files in a directory and all its subdirectories. I wrote a basic function:

Although this is in React-Native, I'm not sure that matters (or maybe there is a react-native solution).

```
let fileList = [];

const readDir = async (dir) => {

  // This line simply reads the contents of a directory, creating an array of strings
  // of all the files and directories inside 'dir'.
  const items = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(dir); 

  items.forEach(async (item) => {
    const f = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(item); // Gets basic information about the item
    if (f.isDirectory === true) {
      readDir(f.uri); // f.uri is the location of the new directory to read
    } else {
      // runs if the item is a file
      console.log("f.uri: ", f.uri);
      fileList.push(f.uri); // A global variable
    }
  })
};

const parentDirectory = "parent_folder";
readDir(parentDirectory);

// Do more stuff here once all files have been read and added to 'fileList'
```

This seems to partially work as all the files in all the subdirectories are consoled out from inside the else {...} segment.

**However, how can I know the loop is complete so I can continue the script and use 'fileList'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `forEach` with `async` they don't work together and you can't await the loop. Use a standard `for .. of` loop, which works nicely with `async/await`

```
const readDir = async (dir) => {
  const items = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(dir);

  for (let item of items) {
    const f = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(item); 
    if (f.isDirectory === true) {
      await readDir(f.uri); 
    } else {
      console.log("f.uri: ", f.uri);
      fileList.push(f.uri); 
    }
  }
}
```

And as `readDir` is `async` as well, you have of course either to `await` it also, or use `then` to continue once it is finished

```
async function foo() {
   const parentDirectory = "parent_folder";
   await readDir(parentDirectory);
   //do some other stuff once readdir is finished.
}
```

or

```
const parentDirectory = "parent_folder";
readDir(parentDirectory).then(_ => {
   //do some other stuff once readdir is finished.

}
```